# Allow folder, but not specific sub-folders

Tags: robots.txt

For robots.txt, how do we allow a folder but not specific sub-folders or pages?

For example my blog is inside `/blog`, but I want to disallow `/blog/wp-admin`.

Would the below code work for what I'm trying to achieve?

```
Disallow: /blog/wp-admin
Allow: /blog
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s sufficient to use

```
Disallow: /blog/wp-admin
```

This will disallow all URLs whose path starts with `/blog/wp-admin`:

- `https://example.com/blog/wp-admin`
- `https://example.com/blog/wp-adminfoo`
- `https://example.com/blog/wp-admin/`
- `https://example.com/blog/wp-admin.php`
- `https://example.com/blog/wp-admin/foo/bar`
- …

Every other URL is allowed to be crawled, including:

- `https://example.com/blog/wp-admi`
- `https://example.com/blog/wp-adm`
- `https://example.com/blog/wp-ad`
- `https://example.com/blog/wp-a`
- `https://example.com/blog/wp-`
- `https://example.com/blog/wp`
- `https://example.com/blog/w`
- `https://example.com/blog/`
- `https://example.com/blog`
- `https://example.com/blo`
- …